# Key sequence off hot key

Tags: scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to be able to use something like Ctrl-Shft-T to trigger a seqquence of keys like "tab - tab - down arrow - down arrow - down arrow - tab - space).

I used to have a program for this in windows but I would really like one for Ubuntu.
Does anyone know of one?

Comment: You of course have searched for a macro program for Ubuntu?

Comment: @David finding an accessible macro program in Ubuntu is not that obvious unfortunatelly. Nowadays we have an excellent text expansion utility, espanso, but that cannot - a.f.a.i.k. be used out of the box to trigger keystrokes, although you can launch commands with it that do that. Not that trivial, no need to downvote in my opinion.

Comment: From what topics can I ask about here. Questions that are primarily opinion-based, such as shopping or hardware recommendations. Are on the off topic list.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a utility that simulates key strokes. On desktop environments that use the Xorg display driver, `xdotool` can do that. That cannot anymore be used in desktop environments on Wayland, such as the default Ubuntu desktop. There, you can use a recent tool `ydotool`. It works on any Linux system.

It is a matter of binding a command to a shortcut key. Include a little pauze, because while the tools send keystrokes, you should not be holding key strokes. This is an example of a command you would then bind to a shortcut key:

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.2 ;  ydotool key 15:1 15:0 15:1 15:0 108:1 108:0'
```

This  would send the keystrokes <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>down</kbd> after a delay of 0.2 ms. In many desktops, only a single command can be given while we need two, a `sleep` and a `ydotol` command. That is why the two commands are wrapped into one, by loading a shell and passing a command to it.